# Как экспортировать массив из `data` элемента на все компоненты?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В корневом элементе создал массив для отрисовки уведомлений. Хочу его экспортировать, чтоб он был доступен всем компонентам через this.

```
<script>
    import set_interceptors from "./plugins/popups.js"
    export default {
        name: 'AppInterface',
        data: () => ({
            popup: {},
            popup_queue: []
        }),
        watch: {
            popup_queue: function(val) {
                if(val.length>0) {
                    this.popup = val[0]
                    if (!this.popup.timeout) {
                        this.popup.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                                val.shift()
                            }, 6000)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            set_interceptors(this.popup_queue); // устанавливает перехватчик на axios, уже работает
        },
    }
</script>
```

Должно вызываться как-то так:

```
<v- .... @click="$popup_queue.push({message:'test'})" >
```

Как устанавливаются переменные с баксом? Можно ли установить её из компонента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

доступ к корневому элементу осуществляется через  `this.$root`
В вашем случае, это будет выглядеть так `this.$root.popup_queue`

Еще можно использовать взаимодействие через глобальную шину событий.

в файле `main.js` добавляете

```
....
const bus = new Vue();
Vue.prototype.$bus = bus;
...
```

Теперь в любом компоненте можете делать так:

```
this.$bus.$emit("test", this.popup_queue);
 this.$bus.$on("test", this.handler);
```

Comment: надо попробовать привязать к руту, но тот компонент не рут

Comment: не понял, чтобы в корневом был доступ к данным дочернего?

Comment: чтоб у дочернего был доступ к дочернему. глобальное состояние такое, но пока не хочу тащить vuex

Comment: хотя лучше бы как-то прибиться к самому экземпляру вуе

Comment: базовым способом взаимодействия между компонентами является взаимодействие через event. https://css-tricks.com/using-event-bus-to-share-props-between-vue-components/

Comment: евент бас это отдельный компонент. но как его прибить к this? Чтоб он был виден с шаблонов и в других файлах проекта. Не к window же его цеплять..